# How to compromise block chain force shield?

Tags: technology, spaceships, energy, space-combat

Set in the distant future, a notorious terrorist group infamously known as "51 Crew" is planning an ambush near the orbit of Thebe, Jovian moon. In the next few hours an armoured shuttle holding a prisoner which is being escorted by 4 fighters will flyby between Europa and Thebe according to their reliable intel, so they hope to retrieve the prisoner before the shuttle had the chance to slingshot away to Mars where the security is tight. Assuming the shuttle and 4 fighters are using block chain technology for their force shield, so each spaceship had their own unique frequency that is not shared among themselves. There is no way for the terrorist to break through the force shield using firepower alone, brute force method is too time consuming and guess work isn't their style either. The working principle of block chain force shield is this: each vessel had a force field generator which requires 1 unique keycode to operate. To allow their own energy based attacks to go through their own force shield but not any other requires a clever network so that's where block chain technology comes in.  Time is running out, is there any way for the terrorist group to compromise the block chain force shield and retrieve the prisoner? No FTL and ET.

Comment: I'm working on developing a smart force shield using p2p network and block chain, basic idea is to prevent friendly fire so now I need to introduce flaw in block chain tech. Otherwise my block chain force shield is too overpowered.

Comment: What comprises "blockchain" in your example? Is this network open to everyone? What are the nodes? Can terrorists plant corrupted nodes to the network?

Comment: @Alexander: yes the network is open to all but it is encrypted.

Comment: (a) A wall of text is difficult to read.  (b) what rule of your world are you asking a specific question about?  This looks like a puzzle at best, storybuilding at worst.  Both are off-topic.

Comment: You may have a problem or two there. Blockchain protocols only protect from *tampering*, not from eavesdropping. The ships would need strong encryption to advise one another about their safe frequencies -- but if they have that, then they don't need blockchain protocols at all.

Comment: I agree with @LSerni and go one better. Block chains specifically protect from tampering of **past** records. While they could be used to prove a ship is "friendly" this would essentially require the record of being friendly to be in the block chain already considered good by the intended victim. Which implies the victim would already have access to that data. It seems unlikely you have enough ships in existence they would not simply have a copy of the entire known valid block chain. What you need is a way to mimic the signature of a ship in the list of known friendlies.

Comment: My suggestion would be to hijack the signature of an existing ship. If the theft was not known it would be considered valid by the victim -> no shields. I'd assume this would be prevented with serious physical security but if you get an access to a damaged ship and use the signature before the loss of the ship/code is recorded in the block chain... Alternately you could spoof a block chain update but that is unlikely with ship registries. Building a ship takes longer than ships are between secured data links so nobody would build remote updates onto the ship systems.

Comment: I don't get the use of this tech: A and B are fighting against C - why would A need to be able to shoot through B's shields? Or are B's shields extra strong against A's weapons, so if C breaks the code C too can have extra strong shields? Could you talk more about the use case of the unbroken tech, so we get a better picture of what the breaking would be good for?

Comment: @bukwyrm: P1 and P2 are attacked by E1, P1 fires a laser which doesn't interact with its own force shield but must be absorbed by P2's shield otherwise friendly fire occurs. Since the force shield affects laser aka em wave so P1 and P2 must allow communication through, that's where block chain comes in.

Comment: This is possibly the epitome of using blockchain where blockchain has absolutely no business being used...

Comment: @user6760 So the combatants cannot see stuff (aka EM wave) during combat because the shield blocks the incoming light from the, say, asteroid they are racing towards?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds as if the force shields are **not blockchain technology** by themselves. They simply require some sort of setting that can be represented by a number. Knowing this setting renders the force shield vulnerable.

You write that the setting must be known by systems on each ship, so that outgoing fire can pass the own force shield. That alone is no reason to encrypt the setting, simply transmit it on a secure, [air gapped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_gap_(networking)) network.

One could imagine that the setting must also be known for sensors and communications, since laser cannon, lidar, and laser communications are just a difference in signal strength. That would mean the other ships in the squadron need the settings as well. Still no need for blockchain technology, simply use an [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) that was exchanged at base.

It sounds as if you fell prey to [hype driven development](https://blog.daftcode.pl/hype-driven-development-3469fc2e9b22). There is no reason why your force shields need blockchain technology.

***One possible solution:*** The owners of the ship don't quite trust their crews, so they installed overrides on their shield. These overrides are signed using public/private key pairs and the integrity of the public keys is assured via blockchain.

*The attack would be an attempt to insert fraudulent override public keys into the system so that the matching private key can be used to deactivate the force shield. This is no different from an attack on any other blockchain infrastructure, e.g. in finance.*

Answer (score 2):

**Spies**

If firepower and brute force can't work, only underhanded tactics can get you through.

You either have a physical spy on one of the ships transmitting the codes or a viral spy transmitting the codes from inside the ship's computer.

Answer (score 1):

You actually want a weak spot in the distributed shielding technology.

You already have one: the ships need to be able to communicate. One-time-pad encryption guarantees that you can neither eavesdrop nor forge communications, no matter your technology.

But if you can prevent the ships from exchanging their shield configurations by jamming, or just by shooting sticky space-tar balls at lidar ports, then each shield gets locked in its current configuration and the network falls out of sync. At that point, you might happen to know that the settings are actually *cyclic* (assume there aren't all that many stable shield frequency configurations after all), so if you can *also* keep the others off your hide for long enough, you can overpower the one ship by brute force.

Duplicate the frequency-hopping of the first shot they fire at you and continue bombarding the ship with that *and* random attempts. After a while, unable to coordinate a "unused" schema with its siblings, the target ship will settle once again on the schema it was using when it first fired - and at that point, the "cloned" shots will get through.